# Duplicate entry '??' for key 'emp_name_unique2'

Tags: navicat

When I design my table, there comes a error:

> Duplicate entry '??' for key 'emp_name_unique2'

[image]

My design table:

[image]

When I save it, comes the error.

Where is the problem?

**EDIT**

My data in `t_employee`:

[image]

Comment: if is your table `t_employee` has data ? can you show me the `t_employee` data?

Answer (score 0):

That is, you see the `emp_name`, if you want to set it to unique, you should make sure the value is unique first.

You have many same `??` in the `emp_name`.

In general, Design table should before add data.